# How to set space in DOM with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why does the simple code below not render the leading space that is included in the JavaScript string?

**HTML**

```
<p id="sample"></p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#sample").text(" "+"space before me");
```

Comment: Where is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When HTML render the text, it trim the value. You can put a non-breaking space if you absolutely want a space (but need to use `.html()`):

```
$("#sample").html("&nbsp;space before me");
```

Or, the good way to do it, use [`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) CSS property

Answer (score 1):

How about using an HTML entity for space and add it as HTML?

```
$("#sample").html("&nbsp;"+"space before me");
```

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers handle whitespace in a defined manner. much whitespace is collapsed to avoid things like indentation of code causing layout changes.

The string you have created in Javascript does contain a space at the beginning. However, if you attempt to render the content using either Javascript, or simply plain HTML, then the whitespace is ignored. See http://jsfiddle.net/KJLbU/

Here are the official HTML whitespace rules: [9.1 White space in the HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.1)

To force a space, you must instruct the browser that you do not want this whitespace to be ignored. You can do this by using one of the HTML space characters. Using a non breaking space is probably the best way. Therefore, your code will become:

```
$("#sample").html("&nbsp;space before me");
```